DASK to_csv() problems due to memory
I'm cleaning my text data and afterwards want to save it to csv. Defined cleaning functions work fine, but when to_csv() part comes, here come the problems as well.
Maybe someone have faced similar problem and has a trick to share with me how it would be possible to solve it? Maybe saving data to csv in chunks or something?
`if name == 'main':
# Initialize the Dask client
client = Client(n_workers=3, threads_per_worker=1,
memory_limit='1.5GB')
print('Dask client created')
PATH = "C:\\Users\\el ruchenzo\\jobsproject\\jobsproject\\lt_data.csv"
reqd = ['description', 'title', 'code']
blocksize = 25e6  # REDUCED FROM 100 GB TO 25 GB

# Load the CSV with Dask
df = dd.read_csv(PATH,
                 usecols=reqd,
                 blocksize=blocksize,
                 dtype={'Code': 'float'},
                 engine='python',
                 encoding='utf-8',
                 on_bad_lines='skip')

# Apply the cleaning function to the 'title' column in the DataFrame
start_time = time.time()
df['cleaned_title'] = df['title'].map_partitions(lambda partition: partition.apply(wrapper_func), meta=('title', 'object'))
gc.collect()
end_time = time.time()
print(f"1. Processing time: {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")

# Apply the cleaning function to the 'description' column in the DataFrame
start_time = time.time()
df['cleaned_description'] = df['description'].map_partitions(lambda partition: partition.apply(wrapper_func), meta=('description', 'object'))
gc.collect()
end_time = time.time()
print(f"2. Processing time: {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")

df.to_csv('cleaned_lemma_*.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8', single_file = False)
print('Saved to csv successfully')

print('Work ended successfully')`

Tried changing workers number, blocksize, memory limit and etc., but nothing seems to work. Also change map() to apply(), tried using df = df.persist(), writing data to csv with pandas in chunks instead with dask, and so on.

Using np.array_split() to split a dataframe into multiple chunks having 10k records each and then writing each chunk individually.
num_parts = len(df) // 10000 + 1

You can change the number of records you want per file by making the change in above line, Or you can have one static Number to define the number of records wanted for each chunk.
num_parts = len(df) // 10000 + 1
split_data = np.array_split(df, num_parts)

for i, data_part in enumerate(split_data):
    print(f"Writing part no:- {i+1} \n")
    file_name = f'Part_{i+1}.csv'
    data_part.to_csv(file_name, index=False)
    print(f"Data Part no:-{i+1} has been Exported as csv successfully!!\n")

